# Lost git branches while pushing a repo to a new origin?

Tags: git

I migrated a SVN repo to Git in a local folder. The branches & tags were properly created as i had a standard svn layout and are visible after a **git branch -a**.
But then, when i push this to gitlab where the real root bare repo will lie in the future, using

```
git push  -u origin --all
```

Only master has been pushed to gitlab even though i added --all at my second push attempt. But not only that, now even locally, **git branch -a** only lists master and origin/master.

What happened? How was i supposed to push all branches? Can i recover the local branches or do i have to restart the migration?

Comment: If `git branch` lists only `master` (`origin/master` is a *remote-tracking* name rather than a branch name), that means you only have the one branch name. So that's all `git push --all` will push. But branch names aren't magically deleted: if they were there at one point, and aren't there at a later point, *something* or *someone* deleted them.

Comment: @torek there is only the 'git remote add origin' and 'git push' calls between the 'git branch' call that list branches and the one the does not, on a computer only i have credentials to use

Comment: So, that means something else must have gone in and done it. What other things are running on your computer? Are you storing your repository in a cloud-synced folder?